# How to display left most and right most arrow symbols to grid list/listview in windows universal app development

Tags: gridview, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

I used grid view list for binding data but how can i get left most and right most arrow symbols for my gridview list which are highlighted in below image..please help me..
[image]

Comment: please help me any one..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a stackpanel with horizontal orientation..

```
<Grid>
    <Stackpanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <YourLeftButton></YourLeftButton>
        <YourMiddleContent></YourMiddleContent>
        <YourRightButton></YourRightButton>
    </Stackpanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some what like this ...

XAML

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged">
    <ListView>
            <!-- Your ListView Content Here ... -->
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>

<Grid x:Name="downArrow" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Background="White" Height="40" Width="60" Margin="2,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Collapsed" >
     <Grid Background="{StaticResource CustomeHoverBlueThemeBrush}" Opacity="1"/>
     <Path Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{StaticResource WhiteThemeBrush}" 
        Data="F1 M 39.8307,37.6042L 36.6641,34.4375L 25.1849,23.3542L 35.4766,23.3542L 50.5182,37.6042L 35.4766,51.8542L 25.1849,51.8542L 36.6641,40.7708L 39.8307,37.6042 Z "/>
</Grid>
<Grid x:Name="upArrow" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="White" Height="40" Width="60" Margin="2,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed" >
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource CustomeHoverBlueThemeBrush}" Opacity="1"/>
    <Path Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{StaticResource WhiteThemeBrush}"
        Data="F1 M 35.8724,37.6042L 39.0391,40.7708L 50.5182,51.8542L 40.2266,51.8542L 25.1849,37.6041L 40.2266,23.3542L 50.5182,23.3542L 39.0391,34.4375L 35.8724,37.6042 Z "/>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainCatagoryScrollViewer.ExtentWidth > MainCatagoryScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth)
        {
            upArrow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            //upArrowImg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        if (MainCatagoryScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth == MainCatagoryScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset)
        {
            upArrow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            downArrow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        if (MainCatagoryScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset == 0.0)
        {
            upArrow.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            downArrow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        if (MainCatagoryScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset < MainCatagoryScrollViewer.ScrollableWidth)
        {
            downArrow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Or also you can define tapped event of grid and change the scrolling index ...

Comment: i used your code, the grid view scrolling when i clicked right and left arrows,,but grid view scrolling hardly, is there any property to scroll smoothly..

Comment: To make it more smoothly you can try animation or you can also edit ScrollViewer style. give it a try